# How to redirect Admin to a specific page and users to another - Laravel 8 jetstream

Tags: php, laravel, admin, panel, middleware

I'm trying to redirect admin to the admin panel page and the users to the homepage

i created new field for usertype and i add the value in database which is "admin"

```
$table->string('usertype')->nullable();
```

then i created this Midlleware (AdminMiddleware):

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Middleware;

 use Closure;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

 class AdminMiddleware
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::user()->usertype == 'admin')
    {
        return $next($request);
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }
    
   }
  }
```

then i add it to Kernel:

```
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
```

and i add the function to RouteServiceProvider and imported the class:

```
public const HOME = '/dashboard';
    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        if(Auth::user()->usertype == 'admin')
        {
            return 'panel';
        }
        else
        {
            return 'dashboard';
        }
    }
```

then i added the route to web.php:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('index');
});

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
return view('index');
})->name('dashboard');





Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum','auth','admin','verified']],function() {
Route::get('/panel', function () {
    return view('admin.dashboard');
});

});
```

and i created two accounts one of them is the admin with value of "admin" for usertype
but when i login it still redirecting me to the homepage

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a simple way which I have been using in my app.

You don't need a middleware for this purpose. Create a controller in the name of `HomeController` or whatever you want.
In you `LoginController` change the property `redirectTo` to a simple route. For example '/home' or even `/` for super simple routes.
Now in `routes/web.php` add this route pointing to a method in `HomeController`.

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@redirectUser');
```

Or

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@redirectUser');
```

Additionally create your own routes which you want to redirect to.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum', 'verified']], function () {
    Route::get('/panel', function () {
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    });
});
```

You can also create routes for number of users.

Now in your `HomeController`, in `redirectUser()` method, add your needs.

```
if (auth()->user()->usertype == 'admin') {
    return redirect(url('route url'));
} else {
    return redirect (url('some other url'));
}
```

Please make sure that you have defined the same URI in your routes file.

You can also redirect users in your `LoginController` as well.
But it works only after logging in. this method will also redirects user to the desired location when they click home button or the logo which contains homepage url.

Hope this one will help you.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the help

Comment: @Sharan do i need to install auth to my project to do this? because i already have jetstream

Answer (score 0):

As comrade Sharan has well explained, for those who are working with jetstream it would be as follows:

1- We create the controller:
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function redirectUser()
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return view('admin.index');
        } else {
            return view('auth.login');
        }
    }

}
```

2- In web.php:

```
Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\\HomeController@redirectUser')->name('homeController');
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum', 'verified']], function () {
    Route::get('/admin', function () {
        return view('admin.index');
    });
});
```

3- In RouteServiceProvider.php:

```
public const HOME = '/admin';
```

With this, what I do is that every time someone enters the main page if they are not logged in, go to the login page and if they are logged in, go to the / admin page, but also if on the admin page I put the full url it redirects to the admin.